# Mapping an entity with multiple references to the same type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

For example `Project` has references (1 optional, 1 required) to the `User`:

```
public class Project {
    public User RequiredUser { get; set; }
    public User OptionalUser { get; set; }
}
```

whereas `User` has many projects:

```
public class User {
    public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be right to configure it like that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Projects)
    .WithRequired(i => i.RequiredUser);

modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(i => i.OptionalUser);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From experience, if you set up separate relations (`RequiredUser` / `OptionalUser`), you'l also need separate `IEnumerable<Project>` properties in your `User` class.

```
public class User {
    public ICollection<Project> Projects_Required { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Project> Projects_Optional { get; set; }
}
```

Your setup then becomes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Projects_Required)
    .WithRequired(i => i.RequiredUser);

 modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(i => i.Projects_Optional)
    .WithOptional(i => i.OptionalUser);
```

You *could* then add a `AllProjects` custom property that combines the two lists, if you so choose. However, it seems a dangerous thing to do, as you need to keep these lists separated **because they address separate relations**. To avoid confusion, I'd keep them separated as much as possible.

If there is a way to set up EF to have both relations end up in the same List property, I haven't found it. It seems hard and dangerous to implement.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Consider `User` having projects he has opened and projects he has been assigned to develop.

Comment: If the two users are functionally different (project creator vs project developer), it makes it a lot easier if you think of them as two different properties of your project; and as different projects for your user.

Answer (score 1):

I think you code would work, but not they way you expect it to:
`ICollection<Project> Projects` will only contain `Project` instances where the `User` is the `RequiredUser`.

I personally would use an intermediate table which has a `IsRequired` flag to map these two entities, but that changes the behaviour a little and introduces a not so easy to handle `many-to-many` relationship:

```
public class Project {
    public ICollection<ProjectUser> Users { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectUser {
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}

public class User {
    public ICollection<ProjectUser> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

The advantage is, that you can have more "optional users" (or required) in one project, but if your requirement is to only have on (required) user you would need to take care of this contraint in your business logic. You could also replace the `bool` with an enum if you have more then two possible "mapping types", e.g. `Owner`, `Developer` and `Tester`.

**NOTE:** If you have no use for this advantage you are better of with Flater's answer.

Comment: This would require additional business logic to make sure only one of each exists. It seems against the intention of the original code, as it now allows for multiples of each. It also introduces a many-to-many relationship where one is not directly needed, which I'd advise to steer clear of adding, unless you need it.

Comment: @Flater: Just added this as a note to the end of my answer. Depending on his specific business case this is MAYBE the better approach.

Comment: @Flater: `It also introduces a many-to-many relationship where one is not directly needed, which I'd advise to steer clear of adding` - can you explain me why you advise against `many-to-many`?

Comment: If a one-to-many relationship is needed, it seems redundant to implement a many-to-many with added businesslogic that ensures only one of each is added. If the RequiredUser and OptionalUser are functionally different (e.g. one addresses the manager of a project, the other a contactperson), piling them on the same IEnumerable introduces a lot of possible errors during future implementations. I could very well be that OP changed the property names to something simple for this question.

Comment: Ok, got you. There I agree. As I said your solution is better if that is his business case, but if it is e.g. like in your comment to Kangkan it could be the case that multiple "optional users" are a possible use-case...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case of circular reference (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) and definitely become a bad design. Think of the design why you need to refer to a `User` in `Project` which is already inside a `User`. Look more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/03/18/398601.aspx

Comment: Suppose the optional user is a secondary person that works on the project in case the first one falls ill. I have no idea what the actual use case is for OP, but there are scenarios where creating a double relation works as intended. It isn't always true that if more than one entity is added, they should be packed in a list/array/ienumerable. If you need to be able to keep the multiple entities apart, different properties seems OK. Secondly,most EF classes have entities relating to eachother, so you can traverse from either direction. I see no reason to assume circular reference issues here.